# MAC OS Laravel Excel doesn't work

Tags: php, excel, macos, laravel-5

recently I changed to Mac. Before that I worked on a Windows. There no problem with this Laravel Excel. Even I can download(Export) the excel sheet also. But in the Mac when I try to export the excel it says that

> The webpage at http://localhost/my_app/public/export might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

In the laravel log file located in /storage/logs it shows the error as

> Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/my_app/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:398

So what should I do. This project is cloned from my private repository in bitbuckect and did a composer update. Are there any issue with that !!

This is My Code:

```
Excel::create($file_to_date, function($excel) use($result)
    {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet1', function($sheet) use($result) 
        {
            $header = array( //assign excel sheet cell headers
                array('First Name',
                      'Last Name', 
                      'Email')
                );
            $sheet->appendRow(array_values($header[0])); // column namesarray_values($data)

            $sheet->row($sheet->getHighestRow(), function ($row) //column names bold
            {
                $row->setFontWeight('bold');
            });
            foreach ($result as $r)//set values to sheet
            {
                $sheet->appendRow($r);
            }
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
```

Can we say something from this. ??

Comment: In case of export, temporary files are created in the `storage/exports` directory by default( you can also change this setting in `config/excel.php`). Check if this directory exists on your system.

Comment: @Vikas I already gave the permission to storage and directory exists. `chmod -R 777 storage` was my command used to give permission. But no good thing still happen.

Answer (score 1):

In your laravel project's directory, change the permission of the folder storage to 755.

Comment: Process is something like this.. when I clicked the export button excel file is downloaded via browser. I don't know the place where it is been created. I think there may be a temp folder. But how to find that ?

Comment: You can find that in the code where the excel is being created. If you're not the developer, I just you ask the person who made it about it.

Comment: I just updated my answer with sample code. can we find the location from this ? please help me

Comment: what I did was `chmod -R 755 storage` . But after that I cant log to the system. Then I changed to 777. Now OK. But problem still there :(

Comment: The file which it shows there as the error in the vendor folder, is the file present there? Also, are you facing any other issues while using the app apart from the excel not being downloaded?

Comment: everything is working fine. Only problem is when try to download. in vendor folder file is there. :(